# How do you generate the non-convex hull from a series of points?

Tags: python, math, geometry, gis, computational-geometry

I am currently trying to construct the area covered by a device over an operating period. 
The first step in this process appears to be constructing a polygon of the covered area. 
Since the pattern is not a standard shape, convex hulls overstate the covered area by jumping to the largest coverage area possible.

I have found a paper that appears to cover the concept of non-convex hull generation, but no discussions on how to implement this within a high level language. 
http://www.geosensor.net/papers/duckham08.PR.pdf

Has anyone seen a straight forward algorithm for constructing a non-convex hull or concave hull or perhaps any python code to achieve the same result?

I have tried convex hulls mainly qhull, with a limited edge size with limited success. 
Also I have noticed some licensed libraries that will not be able to be distributed, so unfortunately thats off the table. 
Any better ideas or cookbooks?

Comment: Possibly related info: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions

Comment: Is the problem well-defined? Do you want *any* non-convex hull that covers the points? Or are there some additional constraints? Consider three points forming an equilateral triangle and a fourth point in the center.  There are (at least) three possible non-convex hulls that enclose those points.

Comment: Wow, all of these varied stackexchange sites really do a good job of moving questions outside of the view of people who could answer them.  :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try looking into Alpha Shapes. The CGAL library can compute them.

**Edit**: I see that the paper you linked references alpha shapes, and also has an algorithm listing. Is that not high level enough for you? Since you listed python as a tag, I'm sure there are Delaunay triangulation libraries in Python, which I think is the hardest part of implementing the algorithm; you just need to make sure you can modify the resulting triangulation output. The boundary query functions can probably be implemented with associative arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately the python bindings for CGAL that you mention no longer compile with the latest versions of boost-python and CGAL.  It appears that the project is not really supported any more.  Are there any other python alternatives?