# Is there a free .NET implementation of an algorithm that calculates alpha-shapes (aka concave-hull)

Tags: c#, .net, gis, computational-geometry

Is there a free .NET implementation of an algorithm that calculates alpha-shapes (aka concave-hull)? Alternatively, an implementation of [this algorithm](http://www.geosensor.net/papers/duckham08.PR.pdf).

I know of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620446/how-do-you-generate-the-non-convex-hull-from-a-series-of-points) thread, but there's nothing specific for the .NET eco-system.

If the answer is simply 'use CGAL + a c# wrapper', then can you please point me to the wrapper as I could not find one, and a sample on how to use CGAL for alpha shapes. The  [CGAL reference manual on alpha-shapes](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_2/Chapter_main.html) is difficult to follow. Specifically, the goal is to take a set of lon/lat points and find an "outline".

Comment: This does seem like an unreasonable question (the title could be reworded to match the first sentence). It certainly seems like something that could be answered factually and with brevity. Either yes - an implementation exists here, or no - as of the date of this post, it does not.

Comment: close-reason: lib finding spree ... nope